# Can anyone help me on where i can start on trying to draw a graph like this in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I played around with tikz-network package but I can't seem to find a way to replace edges with dots and the positioning is a bit weird as well[image: m loops centered at a vertex v_0]
[image]

```
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertex[x=7,y=-12,label=$v_0$]{A}\Vertex[x=8.5,y=-10]{B}\Vertex[x=8.8,y=-8]{C}\Vertex[x=7,y=-6]{D}\Vertex[x=4,y=-10]{E}
\Edge[bend=-20,label=$0^{s_0}$,position=below](A)(B)
\Edge[bend=-10,label=$1^{s_1}$,position=right](B)(C)
\Edge[bend=-10,label=$2^{s_2}$,position=top](C)(D)
\Edge[bend=-45,label=$\dots$,position=left](D)(E)
\Edge[bend=-45,label=$(d-1)^{s_{d-1}}$,position=left](E)(A)
\Vertex[x=3,y=-15]{B1}\Vertex[x=3,y=-17]{C1}\Vertex[x=4.5,y=-19]{D1}\Vertex[x=7.5,y=-16]{E1}
\Edge[bend=-20,label=$0^{s_0}$,position=below](A)(B1)
\Edge[bend=-5,label=$1^{s_1}$,position=right](B1)(C1)
\Edge[bend=-19,label=$2^{s_2}$,position=top](C1)(D1)
\Edge[bend=-25,label=$\dots$,position=left](D1)(E1)
\Edge[bend=-25,label=$(d-1)^{s_{d-1}}$,position=left](E1)(A)
\Vertex[x=9,y=-13.5]{B2}\Vertex[x=12,y=-13.8]{C2}\Vertex[x=14.5,y=-12.5]{D2}\Vertex[x=13.5,y=-11]{E2}
\Edge[bend=-20](A)(B2)
\Edge[bend=-5,label=\text{Loop m},position=below](B2)(C2)
\Edge[bend=-19](C2)(D2)
\Edge[bend=-25](D2)(E2)
\Edge[bend=-25](E2)(A)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Tex.Se. Please provide your code you have so far as a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: Hi, thanks! I just edited the latex codes and a picture of what I had. I just want to add the dots instead of edges and then maybe add names to the loops if possible

Comment: `style=dashed` is what I think you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-network}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[x=7,y=-12,label=$v_0$]{A}\Vertex[x=8.5,y=-10]{B}\Vertex[x=8.8,y=-8]{C}\Vertex[x=7,y=-6]{D}\Vertex[x=4,y=-10]{E}
    \Edge[bend=-20,label=$0^{s_0}$,position=below](A)(B)
    \Edge[bend=-10,label=$1^{s_1}$,position=right](B)(C)
    \Edge[bend=-10,label=$2^{s_2}$,position=top](C)(D)
    \Edge[style=dashed,bend=-45,label=$\dots$,position=left](D)(E)
    \Edge[bend=-45,label=$(d-1)^{s_{d-1}}$,position=left](E)(A)
    \Vertex[x=3,y=-15]{B1}\Vertex[x=3,y=-17]{C1}\Vertex[x=4.5,y=-19]{D1}\Vertex[x=7.5,y=-16]{E1}
    \Edge[bend=-20,label=$0^{s_0}$,position=below](A)(B1)
    \Edge[bend=-5,label=$1^{s_1}$,position=right](B1)(C1)
    \Edge[bend=-19,label=$2^{s_2}$,position=top](C1)(D1)
    \Edge[style=dashed,bend=-25,label=$\dots$,position=left](D1)(E1)
    \Edge[bend=-25,label=$(d-1)^{s_{d-1}}$,position=left](E1)(A)
    \Vertex[x=9,y=-13.5]{B2}\Vertex[x=12,y=-13.8]{C2}\Vertex[x=14.5,y=-12.5]{D2}\Vertex[x=13.5,y=-11]{E2}
    \Edge[bend=-20](A)(B2)
    \Edge[bend=-5,label=\text{Loop m},position=below](B2)(C2)
    \Edge[bend=-19](C2)(D2)
    \Edge[bend=-25](D2)(E2)
    \Edge[bend=-25](E2)(A)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ah, thanks a lot!